# OData: How to convert a System.Uri to Edm.String?

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm building an OData Web API using ASPNetCore. The EdmModel is build like

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<MyType>("MyType");
edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
```

This is MyType

```
public class MyType
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
}
```

This generates an EdmModel like this

```
<Schema Namespace="Test" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
  <EntityType Name="MyType">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Uri" Type="System.Uri" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
</Schema>
<Schema Namespace="System" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
  <ComplexType Name="Uri">
    <Property Name="Segments" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
  </ComplexType>
</Schema>
```

When I query the OData controller I'm getting this response

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44389/v3/$metadata#MyType/$entity",
  "Id": "ID-1234",
  "Uri": {
    "Segments": [
      "/",
      "path/",
      "to/",
      "document"
    ]
  }
}
```

That's not at all what I want. 
**How can I get this to return me the complete URI as a string?**
Is there an attribute I need to add to the model, or is there a way to configure the builder differently?

Comment: Did you find out more about this by any chance?

Comment: No, not yet. I went with strings in the end...

Comment: I opened an issue on the OData repository about this. For reference: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1929